# Run particular Jbehave story from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jbehave

I have a Gradle project with 5 Jbehave Stories and I want to run only one story at a time, but unfortunately I can't find a way to do it.

I've tried to do something like this:
add stories names as parameters and then build project like this:

clean integrationTest aggregate  -Dstory=$Environment (where Environment contains the stories names)
or
clean integrationTest aggregate  -Djbehave.story.name=$Environment

Those didn't worked for me and all the stories were executed each time.
Obviously I am missing something. Anyone has an idea what?